# Add to Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

```
private class Node{
int num;
Node next;
Node prev;
Node (int num){
this.num=num;
this.next=null;
this.prev=null;
}
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter file name");
String fileName = sc.next();
Scanner s = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
while(s.hasNextLine()){
    //No idea           
}
```

File example:

```
 //Skip this 3 6 2
 a 3 b 8
 2 3 4
```

I want to be able to go through each line of the file, skip everything in the comments, and put just the first two numbers of each line into a doubly linked list.  I have been trying for awhile but I am new to doubly linked lists and I can't figure this out.  Also I want to be able to do this without using ArrayList.

Comment: So...where's your doubly linked list instance?

Comment: Well currently you don't have *anything* to do with a linked list. Is the idea that you need to build your own linked list class, or use the one built into Java?

Answer (score 0):

Take each line as a string eg: 
        String temp = sc.nextLine();

Check it the first char is '/', if it isn't then break the 
String into a char[] eg: 
        char [] numbers = temp.toCharArray();
Then you have access to which ever parts of the string you want. 
Sorry about the formatting I'm still in bed answering on my phone, no formatting possible
 ;-)
Actually you could just split the String into a char[] first up, up to you. There are always multiple ways of doing this.

Comment: Scanner s = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
    while(s.hasNextLine()){
    String temp = s.nextLine();
    if(temp !=("/")){
 break;
    }else{
 char[]numbers=temp.toCharArray();
 System.out.println(numbers);
 }
    }   Like this?

Comment: No that checks if the whole line is '/' look up the documentation for String, you're close a little reading and you'll be there.

Comment: Oh when I changed it to temp.startsWith("/") it worked.  Is there a way to check and see if a whole line is blank?

Comment: What would the length of an empty string be?

Comment: Actually isn't there an isEmpty() method in string?? Documentation is your friend.

Comment: So how to I go through the char[] by line and then do things with them

Comment: You need to understand what an Array is first and how that relates to the String you have created it from.
I would suggest sketching out on a piece of paper what you are trying to do and how these variables will look as your method progresses.